# How to retrieve child controls in Xamarin StackLayout

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

`

```
<StackLayout
                        x:Name="xGrpTabBtns"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Spacing="0">



                        <!--#region Tab Button Gerneral-->
                        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <controls:CtrlButton
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                BorderColor="Transparent"
                                BorderRadius="0"
                                BorderWidth="0"
                                Clicked="BtnTabBtnClicked"
                                Style="{StaticResource GuoupStyle}"
                                Text="Gerneral"
                                WidthRequest="180" />

                            <!--#region Bottom-->
                            <BoxView
                                x:Name="xBtnGerneralBotBorder"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorBorder000}" />
                            <!--  Endregion  -->


                            <!--#region Right-->
                            <BoxView
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorBorder000}" />
                            <!--  Endregion  -->

                        </Grid>
                        <!--#endregion-->



                        <!--#region Tab Button Information-->
                        <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <controls:CtrlButton
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                BorderColor="Transparent"
                                BorderRadius="0"
                                BorderWidth="0"
                                Clicked="BtnTabBtnClicked"
                                Style="{StaticResource GuoupStyle}"
                                Text="Information"
                                WidthRequest="180" />

                            <!--#region Bottom-->
                            <BoxView
                                x:Name="xBtnInformBotBorder"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorBorder000}" />
                            <!--  Endregion  -->


                            <!--#region Right-->
                            <BoxView
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorBorder000}" />
                            <!--  Endregion  -->

                        </Grid>
                        <!--#endregion-->
                    </StackLayout>
```

`

I want to retrieve a CtrlButton from the grid.

var buttons = this.xGrpTabBtns.Children.Where(x => x is CtrlButton);
I used it like this, but I couldn't get the button to work.
Is there a way to get all the CtrlButtons inside a stack layout?

var buttons = this.xGrpTabBtns.Children.Where(x => x is CtrlButton);

I tried this, but it was null.

The effect I was expecting is to get all the CtrlButtons inside the Stacklayout.

Comment: Your buttons are children of the Grid, and the Grid is a child of the StackLayout.

Comment: When code does not do what you hope, **set a breakpoint** at that line of code, and examine variables. In locals pane, expand `this`, find `xGrpTabBtns`, expand its `Children`. What do you see as children? You see a `Grid`. Keep going, until you find the `CtrlButtons`. Now you should be able to determine what code to write. Learn to debug what you encounter, and you will be much more effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as Jason said, `your buttons are children of the Grid, and the Grid is a child of the StackLayout`.

You can get the Button with following code:

```
        var children = this.xGrpTabBtns.Children.Where(x => x is Grid); 

        foreach (var child in children) {
            if (child is Grid) {
                var grid = (Grid)child;

                var inerChildren = grid.Children.Where(x => x is Button);
                foreach (var innerchild in inerChildren) {

                    if (innerchild is Button) { 
                        
                       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("find one button here " + ((Button)innerchild).Text);
                    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```